# Diffie-Hellman implementation for crypto exchange Beaxy

Tags: diffie-hellman, cryptocurrency

I am trying to implement authentication mechanism for Crypto exchange Beaxy. https://beaxyapiv2trading.docs.apiary.io/#reference/rest/authentication/login-confirm.

I am having trouble to identify correct input parameters to calculate Diffie-Hellman key.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to implement [emerSSL](https://emerssl.emercoin.com/). This system based on open X.509 standard, and supported in all browsers and command-line tools, like curl or wget.
Exchange Livecoin already use it in production for almost 1year. See the [article and video](https://emercoin.com/en/news/logging-on-to-livecoinnet-with-emerssl), how system works.